# Appending output from a command to array

Tags: arrays, shell, ksh

I am writing a Korn shell script, which runs a command for each iteration of a loop, and tries to append the output from the command to the array (so, makes the output a new array element). I am not too familiar with ksh syntax, but my script looks something like this:

```
# declaring the array
set -A arr
git diff filename | while read -r line; do
    if [ ! -z "$line" ];
        then
        $arr+=($(echo $line | sed -n 'some regex'))
    fi
done
```

As you can see, I am trying to extract a part of `$line`and append it to `$arr` for every iteration of the loop. I am not sure where my syntactical errors are. Any suggestions?

Comment: `$arr=` or `$arr+=` doesn't work for any kind of assignment or append operation -- leave out the leading `$`.

Comment: Also, `echo $line` is buggy -- for instance, if your line contains `/*` then it'll be replaced with `/bin /etc /lib` etc.

Comment: Consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds before asking questions here.

Comment: Also, `arr+=( $(...) )` can add more (or less) than one array element per line processed. Is that **really** what you want?

Comment: (Also, piping into a `while read` loop will work with ksh, but is somewhat gratuitously incompatible with even other shells supporting arrays; consider using the practices suggested in [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) instead).

Comment: To test if the line is not empty, you could use `[[ $line ]]`.  The array assignment needs an index  `arr[$key]+=something`. Instead of using an external command `sed` you can use `Parameter Expansion` like `arr[$key]+=${line/someregex/}` if the regex is not too complex.

Comment: `arr+=( $(...) )` will not work with the associative array defined with `typeset -A` -> `cannot append index array to associative array arr`. That would need a `typeset -a`.